# JSON.parse() not working with variable type string but it works with its content if used directly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting a string from a php page using a simple code that I have used many times for obtaining string responses from php files. this is the first time I am trying to convert this result in json object (or array).

When I use JSON.parse on the response, I get the error shown below. If I pass as parameter of JSON.parse() the text that I have consoled log (i.e copied from the console as it is passed to javascript) it works perfectly.

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        var result = this.responseText;

        resultsObj = JSON.parse(result);
  }
```

the code php is the following:

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) {
    @session_start();
}
header('Content-Type: text/json');
require 'controlleur/connexionDB.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM depart";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$liste .= "[";
$compteur = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if ($compteur != 0) {
        $liste .= ", ";
    }
    $liste .= "{ \"idDepart\" : \"$row->idDepart\", \"idCircuit\" : \"$row->idCircuit\", \"dateDebut\" : \"$row->dateDebut\", \"nbPlaces\" : \"$row->nbPlaces\", \"prix\" : \"$row->prix\", \"titrePromotion\" : \"$row->titrePromotion\", \"rabais\" : \"$row->rabais\" }";
    $compteur++;
}
$liste .= "]";
$reponse = $liste;

echo $reponse;
```

I am getting this error: 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1

the result in the console for the variable "result" is like this:

```
'[
{ "idDepart" : "1", "idCircuit" : "5", "dateDebut" : "2019-06-02", "nbPlaces" : "30", "prix" : "4000", "titrePromotion" : "vfv", "rabais" : "10" }, 
{ "idDepart" : "2", "idCircuit" : "5", "dateDebut" : "2019-06-10", "nbPlaces" : "30", "prix" : "6000", "titrePromotion" : "ded", "rabais" : "4" }, 
{ "idDepart" : "3", "idCircuit" : "5", "dateDebut" : "2019-07-02", "nbPlaces" : "30", "prix" : "7000", "titrePromotion" : "ded", "rabais" : "6" }
]'
```

Comment: What character is at line 1, column 1 ?

Comment: that's all that's there

Comment: Can you show your server side code which return json??

Comment: Is the character an apostrophe ?

Comment: I will post the php code

Comment: Add `console.log(btoa(result))` and post that result.

Comment: This: _the result in the console for the variable "result" is like this:_ Does the console actually show the leading and trailing " ` " character? If so, then the problem is the String is double quoted on the server side.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in php? Your code doesn't handle escaping of characters.

Comment: I have tried with the " ' " and without, same result

Comment: when I use json_encode it rerutned somethig weird, maybe I made a mistake

Comment: You can build an array in php with all the items that you want, and then use json_enocde on that, or build one item at a time and use json_enocde on that, if you enclose it inside "[" and "]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not try to create your json by manipulate string but use internal `json_encode` method.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$response = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $response[] = [
        'idDepart' => $row->idDepart,
        'idCircuit' => $row->idCircuit,
        'dateDebut' => $row->dateDebut,
        'nbPlaces' => $row->nbPlaces,
        'prix' => $row->prix,
        'titrePromotion' => $row->titrePromotion,
        'rabais' => $row->rabais
    ];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Like this, you are 100% sure to have :

- PHP error if your your input can't be encoded.
- Valid json displayed.

--- EDIT ---

I see you code in french, pay attention to special char (like é à ...). You should have UTF-8 encoding everywhere.

- Your php.ini
- your PDO Conn
- your database charset, table and fields.

  $dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  $dbHandle->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Comment: works nicely, thank you for showing me how to do this. You should include the "," after each line.

Comment: Yes, that true :) please check also my edit, that may help you

Comment: thank you some much, I will save your answer for future reference on this

Answer (score 1):

can you try simplifying the php script to this instead?

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) {
    @session_start();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'controlleur/connexionDB.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM depart";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$liste = array();
while($row = $result->fetch()){
  $list[] = [
    "idDepart" => $row->idDepart,
    "idCircuit" => $row->idCircuit,
    "dateDebut" => $row->dateDebut, 
    "nbPlaces" => $row->nbPlaces, 
    "prix" => $row->prix, 
    "titrePromotion" => $row->titrePromotion, 
    "rabais" => $row->rabais
  ];
}

echo json_encode($liste);
```

rather than manually writing the strings, i'm using [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which i think is better to avoid typos.

Comment: yeah, basically like what Yanis-git answered

Answer (score -1):

make sure, you set the header correctly on your php script

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/json');
```

Comment: It's `application/json` and won't make a difference if the code (including the code in the question) doesn't pay any attention to the header.